# How do I set my browser to allow access to my microphone?

Tags: sound, firefox, microphone, speakers, zoom-meeting

I have a `zoom` meeting [hosted](https://superuser.com/q/1646066/977796) on a Microsoft Surface tablet.

This laptop, running Ubuntu, has joined the `zoom` meeting through the web interface (using `firefox`).  The laptop is named Gondor, and is running `groovy` 20.10.

On the gondor laptop, I get a message:

"your browser is preventing access to your microphone."

I've not established that the [microphone](https://askubuntu.com/q/1335597/847449) is working on this laptop.  How do I allow access to the microphone?

In the browser, I [clicked](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1228717) a button to stop blocking the microphone but am still seeing the above message from `zoom` that the browser is preventing access to the microphone.

```
gondor
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 2GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2390  @ 1.86GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1832MHz
          capacity: 1867MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm pti dtherm cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0c
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0c
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:fea00000-feafffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:eff8(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 0c
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:feb00000-febfffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:6f20(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:6f00(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:22 memory:fed1c400-fed1c7ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:80000000-801fffff ioport:80200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:fe800000-fe8fffff ioport:80400000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
                logical name: wlp12s0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:1f:3c:cd:e6:ad
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:30 memory:fe8ff000-fe8fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe600000-fe7fffff ioport:f0000000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:fe500000-fe5fffff ioport:80600000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: enp9s0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:22:19:d1:9c:0b
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=sb v3.04 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:31 memory:fe5f0000-fe5fffff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:6f80(size=32)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:6f60(size=32)
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:6f40(size=32)
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:fed1c000-fed1c3ff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: f2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: memory:fe400000-fe4fffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.0
                version: 05
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:19 memory:fe4ff800-fe4fffff
           *-generic:0
                description: SD Host controller
                product: R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.1
                version: 22
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe4ff500-fe4ff5ff
           *-generic:1
                description: System peripheral
                product: R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.2
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=r592 latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe4ff600-fe4ff6ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: xD-Picture Card Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.3
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list
                configuration: driver=r852 latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe4ff700-fe4ff7ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide isa_compat_mode pci_native_mode bus_master emulated
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:6fa0(size=16)
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD reader
                product: CDRW/DVD GCCT10N
                vendor: HL-DT-ST
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: A100
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:28 ioport:6eb0(size=8) ioport:6eb8(size=4) ioport:6ec0(size=8) ioport:6ec8(size=4) ioport:6ee0(size=32) memory:fe9fb800-fe9fbfff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:fe9fb700-fe9fb7ff ioport:10c0(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0f13
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0103
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
```

---

Update:

The mic on the dell laptop (gondor) definitely [works](https://askubuntu.com/q/1335597/847449) using `textnow` for what that's worth.

As I didn't change anything, I think it's something specific to or about `zoom` itself.  The mic on the laptop is quite poor, but works for testing purposes.

Comment: Here's how to allow access to the microphone https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1228717

Comment: that's a useful link @ArchismanPanigrahi and I've already tried that.  Is there a "good" third party / site xyz to test the mic/browser on?

Comment: Create an new google drive meeting. Or, search "test my microphone online" in an incognito window, and use any of the sites.

Comment: worked with `textnow` website @ArchismanPanigrahi