# How to enable bluetooth on a Dell Inspiron 1420?

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, inspiron, motherboard, lshw

This specific laptop, a Dell Inspiron 1420, certainly has a bluetooth light on the front.

How do I detect the bluetooth bult-in to the laptop?

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ sudo lsusb | grep -i blue
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ sudo lshw
gondor                      
    description: Portable Computer
    product: Inspiron 1420
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: 2HX3ZH1
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable uuid=44454C4C-4800-1058-8033-B2C04F5A4831
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0DT492
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       serial: .2HX3ZH1.CN787838AO01R5.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A10
          date: 12/19/2008
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2390  @ 1.86GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 1471MHz
          capacity: 1867MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm pti dtherm cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 700
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 701
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             clock: 66MHz (15.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: HYMP512S64CP8-Y5
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00007277
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: HYMP512S64CP8-Y5
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 1
             serial: 0000303C
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0c
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0c
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:fea00000-feafffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:eff8(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 0c
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:feb00000-febfffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:6f20(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:6f00(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:22 memory:fed1c400-fed1c7ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:80000000-801fffff ioport:80200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:fe800000-fe8fffff ioport:80400000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
                logical name: wlp12s0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:1f:3c:cd:e6:ad
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:30 memory:fe8ff000-fe8fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe600000-fe7fffff ioport:f0000000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:fe500000-fe5fffff ioport:80600000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: enp9s0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:22:19:d1:9c:0b
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=sb v3.04 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:31 memory:fe5f0000-fe5fffff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:6f80(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@5
                logical name: usb5
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:6f60(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@6
                logical name: usb6
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:6f40(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@7
                logical name: usb7
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:fed1c000-fed1c3ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: f2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: memory:fe400000-fe4fffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.0
                version: 05
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
                resources: irq:19 memory:fe4ff800-fe4fffff
           *-generic:0
                description: SD Host controller
                product: R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.1
                version: 22
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe4ff500-fe4ff5ff
           *-generic:1
                description: System peripheral
                product: R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.2
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=r592 latency=64
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe4ff600-fe4ff6ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: xD-Picture Card Controller
                vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
                physical id: 1.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:01.3
                version: 12
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm cap_list
                configuration: driver=r852 latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe4ff700-fe4ff7ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide isa_compat_mode pci_native_mode bus_master emulated
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:6fa0(size=16)
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD reader
                product: CDRW/DVD GCCT10N
                vendor: HL-DT-ST
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: A100
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:28 ioport:6eb0(size=8) ioport:6eb8(size=4) ioport:6ec0(size=8) ioport:6ec8(size=4) ioport:6ee0(size=32) memory:fe9fb800-fe9fbfff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: FUJITSU MHV2080B
                vendor: Fujitsu
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 0029
                serial: NW99T67292MW
                size: 74GiB (80GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=f071da71-e075-4380-86cb-1d2ca3e090b7 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0
                   description: BIOS Boot partition
                   vendor: EFI
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   serial: cf10a60c-187f-4efe-87f2-2efa242be9c6
                   capacity: 1023KiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-volume:1
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /boot/efi
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: 4a30-fc7e
                   size: 510MiB
                   capacity: 512MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: LVM Physical Volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   serial: HjGnzx-MVuO-sNZo-7gEc-Om5k-YTmj-LfMp84
                   size: 74GiB
                   capabilities: multi lvm2
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:fe9fb700-fe9fb7ff ioport:10c0(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0f13
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0103
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
  *-battery
       product: DELL MN1278B
       vendor: Panasonic
       physical id: 1
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 51000mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ uname -a
Linux gondor 5.8.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:30:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@gondor:~$
```

Yes, it's an old laptop.

No bluetooth detected:

[image: bluetooth]

Comment: Having a Bluetooth LED doesn't mean it has one. Please check at Dell using your service tag. It should give you exactly what parts it has except, of course, any "DIY improvement"

Comment: It was bought used @ChanganAuto so I dunno, and not sure how to open the case.  Perhaps it's very old hardware which just isn't getting picked up?  I should be getting a bluetooth dongle tomorrow.

Comment: Did you try to activate Bluetooth using Fn+F2 or radio On/Off Switch?